# xDB : System.TimeoutException

Tags: xdb, solr

**Environment**: Sitecore 9.0.2 + XP0

All the components are hosted locally.

Error in **poc1.xconnect\App_data\logs**:

```
2019-08-04 16:02:43.787 +05:30 [Error] Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.XdbSearchOperation`1[Sitecore.XConnect.Contact]: System.TimeoutException: A wait for data to be indexed has been timed out.
2019-08-04 16:02:43.787 +05:30 [Error] ["XdbContextLoggingPlugin"] XdbContext Batch Execution Exception
System.TimeoutException: A wait for data to be indexed has been timed out.
```

The changes made in the instance:

1. Deployed custom facet as per the documents in Sitecore.
2. Rebuild the xDB

In SOLR, I have the following warning:

```
2019-08-04 10:45:27.802 WARN  (qtp1330278544-19) [   ] o.a.s.h.a.LukeRequestHandler Error getting file length for [segments_2]
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\Solr\solr-6.6.2\server\solr\poc1_xdb_rebuild\data\index\segments_2
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.size(Unknown Source)
```

Any help will be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the existing xDB index on Solr is bad/corrupt.

1. Turn Solr Off
2. Delete the Data Folder in the xdb and xdb_rebuild Solr Index folders.
3. Turn Solr On
4. Rebuild xConnect xDB Index using the xConnect Collection Search Indexer rebuild command `-rr`: